# Bash case statement while loop array

Tags: arrays, bash, function, case

I am trying to get a script to re-loop on invalid case statement while reading from an array.
This is very similar to the question:
[Bash case statement restart on invalid input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071286/bash-case-statement-restart-on-invalid-input)
but I can't seem to make the code work with my array. I know that I probably need a "while" statement in here somewhere but I can't figure out where it should go.
Here is my original code:

```
stop_services() {
    for i in ${service_array[@]};
do
    read -p "Stop ${i}: (Y/n) " choice
    case "$choice" in
        y|Y ) systemctl stop ${i}; get_status;;
        n|N ) get_status;;
        * ) echo "invalid option";;
    esac
done
}
```

I came up with a solution but it doesn't seem very elegant. By making another function I can then call that function as part of the `* ) echo "invalid option";;` choice.

```
choice_function() {
read -p "Stop ${i}: (Y/n) " choice
        case "$choice" in
                y|Y ) systemctl stop ${i}; get_status;;
                n|N ) get_status;;
                * ) echo "invalid option"; choice_function;;
        esac
}

stop_services() {
        for i in ${service_array[@]};
do
choice_function
done
}
```

Now the function calls itself whenever an invalid option is chosen. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes use a while loop like in the question you linked

Comment: My problem is that I don't know where to insert the "while true" to make it run back through the choices.

Comment: Put the whole thing in a loop, add a break inside where you want it to stop.

Comment: Trying to following just skips to the next item in the array.

Comment: `stop_services() {
 while true
 do
 for i in ${service_array[@]};
do
        read -p "Stop ${i}: (Y/n) " choice
        case "$choice" in
  y|Y ) systemctl stop ${i}; get_status;;
        n|N ) get_status;;
  * ) echo "invalid option"; read choice;;
 esac
done
done
}`